# Cant add custom font onmPDF

Tags: css, fonts, mpdf

I am new mPDF user, actually I want to add Times New Roman for my project, because mPDF does not provide it. So I start to search for the way, and I found these https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html. I try to implement it on my code but still the output file wont load the font. Here is my code

```
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
    __DIR__ . '/font',
]),
'fontdata' => $fontData + [
    'times' => [
        'R' => 'times.ttf',
        'I' => 'timesi.ttf',
        'B' => 'timesbd.ttf',
        'BI' => 'timesbi.ttf',]],
'default_font' => 'times']);
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($hal1config);
$stylesheet = '<style>' . file_get_contents('./gaya.css') . '</style>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($hal1, 2);
$mpdf->AddPage($hal2config);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($hal2, 2);
```

Thanks

Comment: You are overriding correctly set $mpdf variable with a new object of unknown config $hal1config. And method AddPage does not accept an array (i guess there is another array in $hal2config)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. delete this line `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($hal1config);`
2. add to config array this `'tempDir' =>`**DIR** . '/custom/temp/dir/path'`,

Look at my example loading font

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];
$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(
    [
        'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path',
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            __DIR__ . '/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
                'roboto-condensed' => [
                    'R' => 'RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf',
                    'B' => 'RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf',
                ]
            ],
        'default_font' => 'roboto-condensed'
    ]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Стенгазета</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```